# What is the function $\phi$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that: $(1+\beta x \cdot z)^2 - 1 = \phi(x) \cdot \phi(z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given the kernel function in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $$K(x,z) = (1+\beta x \cdot z)^2 - 1$$
What is the function $\phi$ such that $K(x,z) = \phi(x) \cdot \phi(z)$?

I have found a way to decompose the kernel into a formula of all valid kernels: $$K(x,z) = (K_1 + \beta K_2) \cdot (K_1 + \beta K_2) + K_3$$
where

$K_1 = K_1(x,z) = 1$,

$K_2 = K_2(x,z) = x \cdot z$,

$K_3 = K_3(x,z) = -1$.

This seems to simplify the problem, as it isolates $x \cdot z$, but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I replaced $y$ in three places with $z$, as this seemed to be an inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the answer in the wrong way. What you want to do is to simplify the the equation to get every term to be some combination of $x$ and $z$. From there, the solution becomes apparent.

\begin{align*}
 K(x,z) &= \quad (1 + \beta x \cdot z)^2 - 1 \\
 &= \quad 1^2 + 2 \beta x \cdot z + \beta^2 (x \cdot z)^2 - 1\\
 &= \quad 2 \beta (x_1z_1 + x_2z_2) + \beta^2 (x_1z_1 + x_2z_2)^2\\
 &= \quad 2 \beta (x_1z_1 + x_2z_2) + \beta^2 (x_1^2z_1^2 + 2x_1z_1x_2z_2 + x_2^2z_2^2)\\
 &= \quad 2 \beta x_1z_1 +  2 \beta x_2z_2 + \beta^2 x_1^2z_1^2  + 2 \beta^2 x_1z_1x_2z_2 + \beta^2 x_2^2z_2^2 \\
 &= \quad \left(
 \begin{array}{c}
  \sqrt{2 \beta} x_1 \\
  \sqrt{2 \beta} x_2 \\
  \beta x_1^2 \\
  \sqrt{2} \beta x_1x_2 \\
  \beta x_2^2
 \end{array}
 \right)
 \cdot
 \left(
 \begin{array}{c}
  \sqrt{2 \beta} x_1 \\
  \sqrt{2 \beta} x_2 \\
  \beta x_1^2 \\
  \sqrt{2} \beta x_1x_2 \\
  \beta x_2^2
 \end{array}
 \right) \\
 &= \quad \phi(x) \cdot \phi(z)
\end{align*}